# if s[i] in ['A','B','E','F'] then пишет Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива. Как исправить?

Tags: pascal

```
program z1;
var s:string;
i,L,maxL:integer;
begin
readln(s);
L:=0;
maxL:=0;
for i:=0 to length (s) do
  if s[i] in ['A','B','E','F'] then
  begin
    L:=L+1;
    if L>maxL then
      maxL:=L;
  end
  else
    L:=0;
  writeln(maxL);
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индексация строк в Паскале начинается с единицы:

```
for i := 1 to Length(s) do
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка кроется в этой строчке:

```
for i:=0 to length (s) do
```

Почему так происходит:

Пусть есть строка "АБВ"

У нее есть символы с номерами 0 ("А"), 1 ("Б"), 2 ("В")

А длина для нее 3

То есть вы внутри цикла пытаетесь обратиться к символу с номером 3, а есть только номер 2. Потому и

> Индекс находится вне границ массива

Исправляется легко:

```
for i:=0 to (length (s) - 1) do
```

**UPD:**

Непосредственно Паскалем не занимался уже оооочень давно, так что, ориентируясь на другой ответ, правильным будет такое решение:

```
for i:=1 to length (s) do
```